# Uptate a numeric table.column on a CASE

Tags: postgresql

I want to use the following postgresql

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET    column1 = ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN t1.column2 = 'yyy' THEN column1 = 10 * t2.column1 
              WHEN t1.column2 = 'zzz' THEN column1 = 10 * t2.column2 
       end) 
FROM   table2 t2
```

But i get this error: column1 is of type numeric, but the expression is of type boolean Line3: CASE

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `column1 = 10 * t2.column1` returns a boolean because it compares the value in `column1` with the result of the multiplication. But you only want the result of the multiplication there, so you don't need the comparison with `=`

You also don't have an ELSE part, which means that column1 would be set to NULL for all other values of column2. Or - even better - don't update rows that have different values at all by adding the appropriate WHERE clause.

But much more importantly: you need a join between the two tables, otherwise your create a cross product between the two - you don't want that!

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
  SET  column1 = CASE 
                   WHEN t1.column2 = 'yyy' THEN 10 * t2.column1 
                   WHEN t1.column2 = 'zzz' THEN 10 * t2.column2 
                 end
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE t2.t1_id = t1.id --<<< the join condition!
  and t1.column2 in ('yyy','zzz') -- don't update rows that don't need it
```

But I don't really see the need for the CASE expression to begin with if you include the WHERE clause for the values:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
  SET  column1 = 10 * t2.column1 
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE t2.t1_id = t1.id
  and t1.column2 in ('yyy','zzz')
```